# How do I make a swift package available for the Linux platform?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm building a Swift package which should work for MacOS and Linux.

I have tried specifying the platform like so:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .macOS,
        .linux
    ],
...
```

However I get this error:

| /.../Package.swift:10:10: Type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'SupportedPlatform') has no member 'linux'

It seems like this should be allowed according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/supportedplatform):

> Supporting Linux
>
> `static let linux: Platform`
>
> The Linux platform.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In my experience with SPM, we need to specify the platform and version. `.iOS(.v15)`

Answer (score 4):

I know it doesn't sound right, but so far (2/7/2023) you don't have to add `.linux` in your `Package.swift`. This is what I have:

```
platforms: [
    .macOS(.v10_12),
],
```

And the package can be compiled under Ubuntu. Give it a try.